# How to setup CosmosDB when need to search for "like" in string tags

Tags: full-text-search, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning, tagging

I have a 3 tables structure, *Customer*, *Invoice*, *InvoiceItem* that I would like to try to move from the relational DB and store it in CosmosDB. Currently, there are quite intensive queries being run on the *InvoiceItem* table. This *InvoiceItem* table has up to 10 optional *TagX* columns that are basically text that might include the brand, group, type, or something that would group this *InvoiceItem* and make it searchable by saying (simplified):

`SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE Tag1 LIKE '%shirt%' AND Tag2 LIKE '%training%'`

A query like this on a multi-million table can take more than 8 minutes. We are working on the archiving strategy and indexes to speed up the process but it looked to me like CosmosDB could be worth trying in this case, since all of the data is write-once-read-many scenario.

Back to CosmosDB, how do I deal with those string tags in CosmosDB. As a start, I thought about having Invoice and *InvoiceItem* in the same partition with "type" property that would differ them. But then I cannot stick the tags anywhere so they would be easily searchable. Any ideas on how to set it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Textbook database performance issue caused by either lack of, or inefficient indexing.

With that many rows, index cardinality becomes important. You don't want to index the entire field, you only want to index the first n characters of the columns you're indexing, and only index columns you are searching, whether by join or direct where clauses.

The idea is to keep the indexes as small as possible, while still giving you the query performance you need.

With 18 million rows you probably want to start with an index cardinality of the square root of 18m.

That means to hit the index segment you need, you only want to search no more than 5000 index rows, each of which have 400-5000 rows in their segment, at least for sub-second result times.

indexing the first 3-4 letters would be a good starting point. Based on the square root of 18000000 being  4242 and the nearest exponent of 26(3) (assuming alpha characters only) overshooting that. Even if alpha-numeric, 3 characters is still a good starting point.

If the queries then run super fast, but the index takes forever to build, drop a character. This is called "index tuning". You pick a starting point and find the largest cardinality (lowest number of characters indexed) that gives you the performance you need.

If I'm way off because index performance in this DB is way off the mark of a relational db, you'll need to experiment.

As far as I'm concerned, a select query that takes more than a few seconds is unacceptable, except in rare cases. I once worked for a security company. Their license management system took minutes to pull large customers.

After indexing the tables correctly the largest customer took less than 2 seconds. I had to sift through a table with billions of rows for number of downloads, and some of these queries had 7 joins.

If that database can't do this with 18m rows, I'd seriously consider a migration to a better architecture, hardware, software or otherwise.

As index cardinality increases, the performance gains drop to negative as the index cardinality approaches table cardinality, as compared to no index.

As in all things in life, moderation. At the other end of the spectrum, an index with a cardinality of 2 is just about useless. Half of 8 minutes is 4 minutes, assuming a nearly equal distribution.... useless, so indexing a boolean field isn't a great thing to do, usually. There are few hard and fast rules though. Lots of edge cases. Experimentation is your friend.

Comment: Thanks! How does the indexing of the first characters help if the 'LIKE' part hits the middle of the value, for example '%jacket%' in 'winter jacket'?